# Ubuntu Core 20 won't boot on amd64 machine

Tags: boot, dell, 64-bit, intel, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Core 20 (custom model) on a Dell Wyse 3030LT box, but I'm having trouble booting it. I can boot Ubuntu Desktop fine to write the image to the machine's internal storage, but when I proceed to boot Ubuntu Core, I'm faced with a black screen saying `error: no such device: ubuntu-boot` in the corner. I assume it's looking for some partition, which it can't find.

When I look at the storage in the "Disks" application, I see a 1 MB 'BIOS Boot' partition, and a 1.3 GB 'EFI System' partition named 'ubuntu-seed'. Have I possibly done something wrong writing the image?